# Table Centering / alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

Could somebody please help me with centering? I'm essentially wanting to centre the pattern and the text I have in the table. I'll be adding more patterns and will be playing around with the pattern size too.

I used `\tabularx` specifically because I knew how to merge the first row of the table. If there is something better to use them I'm happy compromise. Although something as simple as possible would be great!

Thanks in advance.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{permute}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage[hmargin = 1.25 in, bmargin=.8 in, tmargin=1.2in, headsep=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}


\begin{document}



 \begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth} { | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
 \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Diagram Key} \\\hline
    Pattern  & Pattern Description & Area Type \\\hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}\draw [draw=red, pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=4pt]},pattern color=red] (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0)--cycle;\end{tikzpicture}  & $1$ & 7  \\\hline
    $a$      & $2$  & 7 \\\hline
    $b$      & $2$ & 7  \\\hline
    $c$      & $6$ & 7  \\\hline
\end{tabularx}  



\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` to  your document should help.

Comment: @leandriis Hi, I did try this but this only helped with the text. It didn't work for the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the first screenshot, the `m` column proposed by leandriis does in fact work well.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Diagram Key}\\
    \hline
    Pattern
        & Pattern Description 
        & Area Type\\
    \hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [
            draw=red,
            pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=4pt]},
            pattern color=red
        ] (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}  
        & 1 
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua\\
    \hline
    $a$      
        & 2  
        & 7\\
    \hline
    $b$      
        & 2 
        & 7\\
    \hline
    $c$      
        & 6 
        & 7\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}  

\end{document}
```

[image: Table 1]

To fix the spacing issue, you could just set the baseline of the `tikzpicture` to any value bigger than the white space that you see. Say, `0.5em` for example.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Diagram Key}\\
    \hline
    Pattern
        & Pattern Description 
        & Area Type\\
    \hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=.5em]
        \draw [
            draw=red,
            pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=4pt]},
            pattern color=red
        ] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}  
        & 1 
        & 1\\
    \hline
    $a$      
        & 2  
        & 7\\
    \hline
    $b$      
        & 2 
        & 7\\
    \hline
    $c$      
        & 6 
        & 7\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}  

\end{document}
```

[image: Table 2]

#### Edit

The OP wants there to be an equal amount of white space before and after the rectangle. This can easily be achieved by adding `\vspace{.5em}` before and after the `tikzpicture` environment. To have a more modular code, you can add the `\vspace{.5em}` to the begin and end document hooks by using `etoolbox`'s `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `AfterEndEnvironment` commands. Ideally, you'd also only call this, if inside a `tabularx` environment to make sure that any `tikzpicture` outside a table will not be affected by this new spacing.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Libraries
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

% Vertically center the X cells
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

% Add a vspace to the tikzpicture if inside a tabularx
\newtoggle{intabularx}
\togglefalse{intabularx}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{
    \toggletrue{intabularx}
}
\AtEndEnvironment{tabularx}{
    \togglefalse{intabularx}
}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{
    \iftoggle{intabularx}{\vspace{.5em}}{}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{
    \iftoggle{intabularx}{\vspace{.5em}}{}
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Diagram Key}\\
        \hline
        Pattern
            & Pattern Description 
            & Area Type\\
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=.5em]
            \draw [
                draw=red,
                pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=4pt]},
                pattern color=red
            ] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
            & 1 
            & 1\\
        \hline
        $a$      
            & 2  
            & 7\\
        \hline
        $b$      
            & 2 
            & 7\\
        \hline
        $c$      
            & 6 
            & 7\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table 3]

Comment: Hi, it seems that the `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` only works when there is a good chunk of text to raise the height of the row. I'm in need of a solution that will place equal white space at either side of the pattern, where it's not dependent on the text in the other cells.

Comment: @trieasyboid No, the `m` columns of the `array` package vertically center the cell content. This white-space issue has nothing to do with the specific command. If you want an equal amount of whitespace before and after your `tikzpicture` just add some with `\vspace{.5em}`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible to add some vertical spacing in the first realization, but you should really consider the second one.

Centering a `tikzpicture` is actually easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin = 1.25 in, bmargin=.8 in, tmargin=1.2in, headsep=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{| *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Diagram Key} \\
\hline
Pattern  & Pattern Description & Area Type \\
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]
  \draw [draw=red, pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=4pt]},pattern color=red]
    (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
    & $1$ & 7  \\
\hline
$a$ & $2$ & 7 \\
\hline
$b$ & $2$ & 7  \\
\hline
$c$ & $6$ & 7  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular*}{0.7\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Diagram Key} \\
\midrule
Pattern  & Pattern Description & Area Type \\
\midrule
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]
  \draw [draw=red, pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=4pt]},pattern color=red]
    (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
    & $1$ & 7  \\
$a$ & $2$ & 7 \\
$b$ & $2$ & 7  \\
$c$ & $6$ & 7  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following based on `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`  and `cellspace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin = 1.25 in, bmargin=.8 in, tmargin=1.2in, headsep=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{0.5\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{| *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}0{X}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|0c|}{Diagram Key} \\
\hline
Pattern  & Pattern Description & Area Type \\
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [draw=red, pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=4pt]},pattern color=red]
    (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
    & $1$ & 7  \\
\hline
$a$ & $2$ & 7 \\
\hline
$b$ & $2$ & 7  \\
\hline
$c$ & $6$ & 7  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```